# express-validator: skip further validation in custom validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express

I am using [express-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator) to validate my request data. According to the docs to add them we have to declare them like this

```
app.use(expressValidator({
 customValidators: {
    isArray: function(value) {
        return Array.isArray(value);
    },
    gte: function(param, num) {
        return param >= num;
    }
 }
}));
```

I added a validator to it like the docs. but I can only return true or false.

I want to make sure that based on the condition validator skip further chain validation.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in stages. Here I first check whether username is set, and only if that passes do I then do an expensive async validation.

```
req.checkBody('username')
        .notEmpty().withMessage('Username is required.');

req.getValidationResult().then(result => {
        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).send(result.mapped());
        }

        req.checkBody('username')
            .isUserNameAvailable().withMessage('Username is not available.');

        req.getValidationResult().then(result => {
            if (!result.isEmpty()) {
                return res.status(400).send(result.mapped());
            }
            next();
        });

})
```

Comment: well if i have three to four validation for one field or different fields, don't you think code will mess up. there should be the other way to this.